# Why won't this loop to add CustomDocumentProperties work?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I'm trying to add a few custom document properties to a folder of word documents.

I know that the loop itself works fine, because I used the same loop with different code to modify and then update pre-existing custom document properties.

The code to add custom document properties also works, I tested it by running it in it's own macro for a single document, which worked fine.

Since the loop works and the code within the loop also works, I just can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Here's the code:

```
Sub add_custom_docproperties()

Dim file
Dim path As String

Dim filepath As Variant
filepath = InputBox("Please enter the filepath for the files you want to 
update.", "Input Filepath", "Copy filepath here...")
Select Case StrPtr(response)
Case 0
endednotification = MsgBox("The macro has been ended.", , "Notification")
Exit Sub
Case Else
End Select

path = filepath & "\"

file = Dir(path & "*.*")

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While file <> ""

    Documents.Open FileName:=path & file

        Check = MsgBox(path & file, , "Check")

        ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="firstdocprop", 
          _LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="The First One"
        ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="seconddocprop", 
          _LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="Second"
        ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="thirddocprop", 
          _LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="Third"

'original example from:
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba
/articles/documentproperties-add-method-office

    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.Close

    'set file to next in Dir
    file = Dir()

Loop

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "The macro is complete."

End Sub
```

As you can see I have a comment there with the first example I tried from msdn, which I modified.

Thanks in advance for any help, even if you could just point me to a resource explaining where I've gone wrong or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word does not recognise the changes to the `CustomDocumentProperties` as being sufficiently important to actually save the document when you execute the `Save` command - unless you had made other changes it just decides to ignore the `Save`.

You can force a save by telling Word that the document has not been saved since it was last changed:

```
ActiveDocument.Saved = False
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it would be something simple. It was driving me nuts.